# Remove type declaration to match parent

Tags: php, laravel, string, types, properties

I am preparing a PHP.doc and I have a code like this.

```
     /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected string $signature = 'signature';
```

It gives a red underline for string and says "Remove type declaration to match parent". How can I solve this?

PHP version: 8.2.
Laravel version: 10.33

Without string it works, but I want to add it somehow.

Comment: Are you extending some class that has a different type declaration (or none at all) for that property? Also, where exactly are you seeing that error? Is it a PHP error when you run your app, or is it in your editor when you wite the code (which I'm guessing since you say "red underline")?

Comment: As you said I am extending a class named LogBaseModel. Seems like I am getting this error because of this. And yes, I am seeing the error in my editor. @M.Eriksson

Comment: And I'm guessing that the parent class has a different type declaration (or none) for that property? You simply can't change properties type declaration in child classes (for public/protected properties since they are inherited)

Comment: It seems like that. Thanks for the answers. It helped a lot. @M.Eriksson

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write "$signature" after declaring "@var string"? Like below

```
@var string $signature
```